# How can I remove a runestone from a character?

Tags: android, talisman

You can replace runestones with other runestones, but there doesn't seem to be a way to remove one from the slot entirely.

Is there a way I've missed? (Using Android version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! (Thanks to the very helpful devs at nomad games for a quick reply!)

Just reselect the runestone again (select slot, select same runestone) and it's gone!